# delete users and all its related records

Tags: database

Is there a way I could run mysql query from the backend to delete all the users and its related records except master-login.

There are some modules that help to do it or a via drush command but I am trying to do this from the backend database.

I am not sure about the how all the tables are maps. instead of figure it out I am trying to get a quick help here.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You can install the [Delete All](https://www.drupal.org/project/delete_all) module which provides some command line Drush commands to remove all content and users *safely*.

> This module is used to delete all content and/or users from a site.
>   This is mainly a developer tool, which can come in handy in several
>   cases, listed below.
>
> The usual way to do this is to go to Administer -> Content then select
>   all the nodes and delete them. This works if you have a handful of
>   nodes only. If you have hundreds or thousands of nodes, then it is not
>   a practical solution.
>
> Another option is to directly delete the nodes from the node table in
>   the database. This does not work properly, since there are also
>   comments, and many tables for add on modules that needs to be cleaned.
>
> - This is a test site that the client was using for a period of time,
>     and they must clean it up before starting with real data.
> - You are
>     testing something that creates a lot of nodes (e.g. aggregator), and
>     want to do it over and over again.
> - You created a site in the past and
>     want to replicate it again, but with new content.
>
> Note that for nodes,
>   comments and all additions to nodes that contributed modules may have
>   added. For users, any additional module data will also be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following script to delete all users.

```
$table_select = db_select('users', 'u')
              ->fields('u',array('uid'))
              ->condition('name','master_login_name','!=') // Put admin name here in place of 'master_login_name'
              ->execute()
              ->fetchAll();



foreach($table_select as $users)
{
user_delete($users->uid); 
}
```

user_delete function will delete users from drupal tables.[user_delete](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_delete/7)

Comment: above query will delete only user but how to delete user related data i.e, node etc...

Comment: if you want to delete only node part then firstly you have to get nodes id according to users id. and use this function node_delete($nid).